# Supporting multiple screens in android

Tags: android, screens

I have developed a game in android,but i'm facing many problems with the screen sizes I heard that we should create separate folders like(layout-small,layout-normal,layout-large,layout-xlarge) in the res folder and should maintain all xml files in them.

But my confusion is how to retrieve particular xml from particular layout folder what is the code should be written in the Activity..?
Please help me to solve this by an example.
Thanks

Comment: Little help, on this page : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html You'll find a "how to support multiple screen size" category. Reading it might answer some of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont choose from which folder you read the xmls. Android does it for you depending on the dpi and the size of the screen its running on.

This is what helped me:
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: your suggestion means a lot and its helpful for me thanx

Comment: I'm having a doubt here also if we place xml files in particular folders then what will be the main res/layout folder contents will do..? i mean to which type of screen size does it support..?

Comment: the simple layout is the normal layout and default one. It support medium devices.
res/layout/my_layout.xml  // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml  // layout for extra large screen size

this is from http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html.

Comment: I was also very confused with all these aswell. You want to support a phone and a tablet? thats your goal?

Comment: then follow the guide ive sent you. I made 1 layout, 1 layout-sw600dp and 1 layout-sw720dp and all 5 drawable folders(ldpi,mdpi,xxhdpi etc) and it works in both tablets and phones. Also in your drawable folders you must make different image sizes for each folder

Comment: I also added this code but am not sure if it will work without this, you can try it out:     <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />

Comment: <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

Answer (score 1):

I believe Android does it automatically. The operating system detects when the display is a certain orientation / size and uses the layout from the appropriate folder (if present) without you having to do anything apart from create the layout files.

Comment: Related: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: your suggestion means a lot and its helpful for me thanx

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to create xml for each screen size.
store your xml in your layout folder.
and as per the size (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi) create images.(read developer guide for image size)